# Find where an object is instantiated

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am trying to use reflection to identify where my object was created. For example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public static class Students
{
    public static class FirstGrade
    {
        public static MyClass John = new MyClass { Id = 1, Message = "Some Text" };
    }
}
```

Now somewhere else in my code I want to use the MyClass object John and with that object I want to determine where John was created so that I can identify that he is a student in First Grade. I would also like to know the object name "John" as this could change:

```
MyClass student = Students.FirstGrade.John;
```

Comment: __Definitely__ rethink this. It would be _much much much_ easier for you to just tag the object itself with the grade.. rather than use reflection. E.g: `public int Grade { get; set; }`. You'll quickly find what you're doing is very painful.

Comment: Thanks Simon! I thought of that as well. The reason why I can not do this is because I will also have a generic category and the same John variable in there with a different message. So when my application runs it will call the generic John and at run time if it detects that there is a specific First Grade John, I want the generic value to be replaced by the specific one. Sorry if this is hard to understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think below is what you are asking for.  Alternatively if you want to know where an object was truly created and not just where it is referenced then you could access the a `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace` object inside the `MyClass` constructor.

As others have mentioned, it seems like the design should be reconsidered.

```
public static class Students
{

    public static class FirstGrade {
        public static MyClass John = new MyClass { Id = 1, Message = "Some Text" };
    }

    public static class SecondGrade {
        public static MyClass John = new MyClass { Id = 2, Message = "Some Text" };
    }

    public static Type FindStudent(MyClass s, out String varName) {
        varName = null;
        foreach (var ty in typeof(Students).GetNestedTypes()) {
            var arr = ty.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
            foreach (var fi in arr) {
                if (fi.FieldType == typeof(MyClass)) {
                    Object o = fi.GetValue(null);
                    if (o == s) {
                        varName = fi.Name;
                        return ty;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void FindJohn() {
        String varName = null;
        Type ty = FindStudent(SecondGrade.John, out varName);
        MessageBox.Show(ty == null ? "Not found." : ty.FullName + " " + varName);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! I used the FindStudent method coupled with another method to recursively find all nested types (since it may be more than one level deep). Thanks!